# How to reset scroll position on a route change?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I spend my first couple of hours with Angular JS and I am trying to write a SPA with it. However, on changing route, the scroll position remains at its current position after changing routes. This means that if someone read through half of the text on page two, this person will end up in the middle of page when two after changing to the second page. (Given that the pages are equally long.)

When I look for solutions I only find people asking for the opposite, i.e. they do not want to change the scrolling position once they change pages. However, I failed to reproduce even that. I wonder if the development of Angular JS got ahead of this and the sources I consulted were outdated.

I created a minimal version that demonstrates my problem (simply add two files `sample1.html` and `sample2.html` with random content to make it work.):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en"><title>SPA sample</title></head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
<div style="position: fixed;">
  <a href="#/">Main</a>
  <a href="#/other">Tutorial</a>
</div>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'noOp',
                    templateUrl: 'sample1.html'
                })
                .when('/other', {
                    controller: 'noOp',
                    templateUrl: 'sample2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
    myApp.controller('noOp', function ($scope) { });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be looking for [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

Comment: I read through it. So should the controller which is now noop get this anchor scroll and apply it? Sorry, I'm pretty new to angular.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As per the `ngView` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#ngView-arguments):

> autoscroll(optional) string:
>
> Whether ngView should call $anchorScroll to scroll the viewport after
>   the view is updated.

So all you have to do is change your `ng-view` call to turn on autoscroll like so:

```
<div ng-view autoscroll></div>
```

Comment: Above answer has solved half problem of mine, I want to do the same on page reload as well. Could you please guide how that can be done?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt

Answer (score 12):

After each route change there is an event fired on the `$rootScope`: `$routeChangeSuccess`. In the most basic scenario, just listen to this event and reset the scroll position to `(0,0)`:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(){
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
})
```

In a bit more advanced case you can store, for each url, the last position before leaving the url -- then you should listen on: `$routeChangeStart` as well.
Very primitively, the storing could be made on the `$rootScope` itself, but I would prefer to use JS hash object and keep it as simple angular value instead.
If storing the last position should be made permanent (e.g. in `localStorage`), then you can consider use of angular service.

Comment: Continuous listening to viewport scrolling seems to be required, since upon back or forward button click any event will happen too late to record the offset.

Comment: @Srg does your page fully reloads or is it a SPA? if the latter then I am pretty sure dirty checking is not required.

Comment: I've yet to see one SPA cleanly supporting the now 1 year old iOS7 bfCache navigation using **swipes**. The problem is it takes time to apply any change to a page and there just isn't any. If you haven't noticed it, (get a hold of iOS7+ device, open an SPA, drill down,) swipe back almost to the end, take a good look and then release. There is always a noticeable glitch while the SPA returns to the previous state.