# How make same area when use $route.Reload()

Tags: angularjs, reload

After my api call i used

```
 $route.reload()
```

I want it show on same area after reload.
I have 2 button on my bottom of page.when i reload it, reload and come to center of page. but i want to stay on bottom of my page after reload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset scroll position on a route change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779753/how-to-reset-scroll-position-on-a-route-change)

Comment: that is not same. My question is different

Comment: Route change/reload?

Comment: A better way could be to use UI-Router and store your position in `$state`

Comment: Can you tell how to use $state.reload();

Comment: Please refer to the UI Router doc https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/state.html